# Logging network activity of LAMP server using BASH

Tags: networking, proxy, logging, lamp, netcat

I've got a Fedora LAMP server on Amazon EC2 functioning as a HTTP pseudo-proxy (Sorry, don't know the terminology- It's not a true proxy where requests are relayed through apache, rather client requests are being translated by a PHP script, which then sends a new request.)

I'd like to be able to fully log the HTTP cycle

1. CLIENT -> PROXY
2. PROXY -> SERVICE
3. SERVICE -> PROXY
4. PROXY -> CLIENT

I'm hoping to do this using BASH tools- thinking netcat? Looking for advice and examples.  Thanks!

Comment: netcat is a Unix/Linux tool rather than a Bash tool. Perhaps you mean "using Linux tools in a Bash script"?

Comment: Correct- I just want to be able to use available shell tools vs having to install new software

Comment: Gotta say I'm surprised by the radio silence- didn't think this was an obscure question- Does ServerFault not yet have the critical mass of StackOverflow..?

Comment: StackOverflow seems to have far more users then ServerFault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I'd use both netcat and tcpdump. tcdump is a *nix tool that dumps the traffic on a network. You can specify things like the NIC you want to dump, the protocol or the source/destination ips.

It's very useful when debugging or troubleshooting networking problems.

More info about tcpdump [here](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html) and some good examples [here](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/283/simple-usage-of-tcpdump/).

Comment: Thanks Marcos- How do the two compare?  When would you use one over the other?  Also, have you used Ethereal, or any other tcpdump guis?

Comment: @Yarin: in this specific case I'd use tcpdump. And yes, I've used Ethereal and it's great as a Tcpdump GUI (the best, imho :))